# Can't install Ubuntu on HP Series 2000, blank screen

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have purchased a new laptop HP series 2000 with Core i3 2nd generation processor..
However only blank screen comes during setup..I have tried with ubuntu 12.04 also..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! All caps title wasn't necessary. Please edit the answer to include, whether you have changed bios boot order to boot from CD or USB.

Comment: I booted from CD.

Comment: I read on forums that this may be problem related to  integrated graphics in Core i3 processor..

Comment: Can you boot to the point where you can see "try Ubuntu" and "install" options?

Comment: yes only the first screen appears there after only blank screen ..

Comment: I have also tried setting SAFE GRAPHICS mode by pressing F4 and nomodeset by pressing F6 from the screen..but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem is in your integrated Graphics driver. You may try to use alternate install CD which may solve this kind of problem.

- Download the iso from the below link. (32bit or 64bit)

  32 bit - [Download 32bit version of alternate install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso)
  64 bit - [Download 64bit version of alternate install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso)
- Then burn the iso in a CD or create a bootable USB
- Reboot from the alternate install CD and install from there.

Go to these links to get help on installing from alternate CD:

- [Official Ubuntu installation guide for i386 (32bit)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/index.html)
- [Installation guide for amd64 (64bit)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/index.html)

  Also see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) for a general discussion.

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know the results :) thank you :)

Comment: How to install from ubuntu alternate install cd..Is there any link where it is explained ?

Comment: @Manish see my updated answer

Comment: I have gone through this guide earlier :) ..I will update after trying the alternate cd

Comment: @Manish, please update your links - http://askubuntu.com/questions/389440/update-this-pls