# Update this pls

Tags: system-installation

[Can't install Ubuntu on HP Series 2000, blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183885/cant-install-ubuntu-on-hp-series-2000-blank-screen)

Can someone post links again ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183885/cant-install-ubuntu-on-hp-series-2000-blank-screen My bad not link in top this link

Comment: it's the same link...

Comment: I got it, he means that the links in this answer are broken. http://askubuntu.com/a/183892/10698 I would say google is your freind... But maybe that's just me..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2afu7q this 2 i can find there...

Comment: yea thats broken links...

Comment: Ask in a comment on the question/answer where the links are broken. Don't start new questions about other questions.

Comment: And please use proper language. Take the time to explain what you mean, so everyone can follow you and get down on fixing actual issues instead of having to ask what you meant, but then having not enough spare time to fix anything. Really, the benefit of shortening "please" to "pls" did gain nothing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page may be better...

Here is my updated version of [Can't install Ubuntu on HP Series 2000, blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183885/cant-install-ubuntu-on-hp-series-2000-blank-screen)

---

It seems a problem is in your integrated Graphics driver. You may try to use alternate install CD which may solve this kind of problem.

- Download the iso from the below link. (32bit or 64bit)

  #### 32 bit - [Download 32bit version of alternate install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso)

  #### 64 bit - [Download 64bit version of alternate install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso)
- Then burn the iso in a CD or create a bootable USB
- Reboot from the alternate install CD and install from there.

Go to these links to get help on installing from alternate CD:

- [Official Ubuntu installation guide for i386 (32bit)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/index.html)
- [Installation guide for amd64 (64bit)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/index.html)

  Also see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) for a general discussion.

Comment: Don't Mind :-) - Have suggested an edit for http://askubuntu.com/questions/183885/cant-install-ubuntu-on-hp-series-2000-blank-screen as well.